# Insert stars between lines of a file

Tags: python, file

I am trying to put stars between lines of a file, I tried to get the position of handle at end of each line and start writing, but the result inserts stars at the end of the file. can anyone explain why this happens?

````
with open('exercise3.txt','r+') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.seek(0)
    for i in range(len(lines)-1):
        line = file.readline()
        oldpos = file.tell()
        file.write('\n' + 20*'*' + '\n')
        file.seek(oldpos)```
````

Comment: You can already iterate over the file line by line just doing `for line in file:` so take out the `lines = file.readlines()`. I don't know if that's causing your issue, but it's just noise and unnecessary.

Comment: @mechanical_meat I wanted not to read the last line :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply read all lines and add * between them like this:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines() //This will return a list of lines
newFileLines = []
//Go trough indexes of lines if index%2 != 0: //Check if its even or odd index(if odd, add the line, if even, add stars -> first line, will be added, second index, will add "*" adn the next line and so on)
for index in range(len(lines)): 
        newFileLines.append(20*"*" + "\n")
    newFileLines.append(lines[index])
file.close()
file = open("newFile.txt", "w")
file.writelines(newFileLines)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you @AlexandruDuDu :) but I actually was curious why my code didn't work! why did it write at the end of the file?!

Comment: Because `write` doesn't write to the file using the `seek` value, it will always write at the end of the content. To write somehwere else you need to process the lines in python pipeline and add what you need, then write the content to output file.